# MVC post action ViewModel is returned as NULL

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post the form values back to the controller. But in the action, I get the ViewModel as null.
Here is ViewModel

```
public class CommunicationDetailsViewModel
{
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Country { get; set; }

    public List<State> State { get; set; }

    public List<City> City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32), Required(ErrorMessage ="Address is required")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [StringLength(32), Required(ErrorMessage = "Building name is required")]
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(CommunicationDetailsViewModel communicationDetailsViewModel)
{
        return View();
}
```

Does it have to do anything with the Kendo UI for MVC? Because this is the very first time I am using Kendo UI.  Below is the view:

```
    @model WebAPI.ViewModels.CommunicationDetailsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Supplier Information";
}

<h4>Supplier Details</h4>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "SupplierInformation", FormMethod.Post ))
{
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Organization name")
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationName).Name("txtOrganization").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Organization Name" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Country")
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCountry").DataTextField("CountryName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.Country))
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("State")
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlState").DataTextField("StateName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.State))
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("City")
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("ddlCity").DataTextField("CityName").DataValueField("Id").BindTo(Model.City))
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Address")
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.Address).Name("txtAddress").HtmlAttributes(new { @class="k-textbox required", placeholder="Address", @maxlength = "32" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Building name")
            @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => Model.BuildingName).Name("txtBuildingName").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Address", @maxlength = "32" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnSave").Content("Save").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", @class = "k-button k-primary" })

}
```

And interestingly, if I use **FormCollection** instead of my ViewModel, I am able to get the values in the action.
What am I missing here? Must be something stupid.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Similar issue: https://www.telerik.com/forums/editorfor-with-the-name-method-returns-null => just remove `Name()` function if you use `...For()` helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem here is caused by you change name by `Name` function. Note that MVC binding properties by name attribute of input tag so don't change it

For example you use

```
    @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationName).Name("txtOrganization").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Organization Name" })
```

You change name of input from `OrganizationName` to `txtOrganization` that may cause MVC cann't binding properties exactly. You should keep its original name or ignore change its name like this

```
    @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.OrganizationName).Name("OrganizationName").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textbox required", placeholder = "Organization Name" })
```

Comment: Such a dumb I am. That was it. I changed the name of the controls to that of the properties and it worked. Thanks.